# Can I push a reference to a vector with a longer lifetime if I pop() it back just after?

Tags: rust

Here, I'm not able to add `thing` to vector because its lifetime is different than `'a`:

```
pub fn foo<'a>(vec: &'a mut Vec<&'a Thing>) {
    let thing: Thing = new_thing();
    vec.push(&thing);
    // do stuff with vec
    vec.pop();
}
```

Notice that I always remove it from the vector, and the vector isn't reordered further, so this operation should be safe. I think it would be hard to convince that to the compiler, but is there any trick to achieve the same?

Comment: no, I don't think so, your algo look strange, to solve your problem you should give your real problem instead of a strange solution.

Comment: Something could always panic in the middle.

Comment: Even if this is somehow possible with `unsafe`, I wouldn't recommend doing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely not in safe Rust. The compiler has no idea what `Vec::push` and `Vec::pop` do. All it knows is what it can tell from the function signature — that you have to push the same type that the `Vec` is parameterized with.

Doing this in unsafe Rust is *probably* possible, but unsafe code is **tricky** to get right. As [loganfsmyth mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391057/can-i-push-a-reference-to-a-vector-with-a-longer-lifetime-if-i-pop-it-back-ju#comment89754805_51391057), if you somehow push an "invalid" value into the `Vec` and then a panic happens, that value is still in the vector after the function has exited. Now the destructor of the `Vec` can access invalid memory, subverting Rust's guarantees. This is A Bad Thing.

There's probably a better solution to your real problem. Possible avenues:

- Use [`Iterator::chain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.chain) and [`iter::once`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.once.html) to combine the values into one iterator.
- Create a wrapper type around a slice and a single value that exposes the operation(s) you need.